# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image: this is the ss of the error am getting and the code]

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
implementation 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
compileOnly 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13
```

this is my build.gradle code
i have attched the image of my code and therror am getting pls help me with resolveing this error

Answer (score 2):

Update the dependency to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

Also it seems you are using the android support libraries. But the newest version of firebase support `androidx` and not `com.android.support`. Therefore you need to do the following:

```
The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.
```

Check the following for more info:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17

Answer (score 1):

There is no Firebase Cloud Messaging Library with Version `19.2.0`

Change it to :

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0
```

If you don't want to migrate with android x just try using :

Versions before [17 June](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17). I don't recommand this as solution.

Please Read on this you will find [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Comment: i have tried it but im getting that errors sdk version 28 in build gradle

Comment: This is not solution if you don't want to migrate with androidx just lower the version to the `Cloud Messaging version 19.0.0`

Comment: after changing getting an error                                                                                                          ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-59:19 to override.

Comment: @Ajith i suggest to Migrate with [Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: i have migrated to android x already

Comment: Please post your gradle in code properly